# Android xml reference within xml doesn't work

Tags: android, android-layout

I want to apply the new material design to my android app and have a small problem with my xml file.

```
<item name="keyline_margin">16dp</item>
<item name="keyline_margin_content">72dp</item>

<!-- bla bla bla -->

<item name="navigation_margin_content">@dimen/keyline_margin_content</item>
```

I want to reference from "navigation_margin_content" to "keyline_margin_content" but Android Studio can't resolve symbol "@dimen/keyline_margin_content"...

It works already with my string and colors. I rebuilt my project already.

Comment: are you sure the files is dimens.xml?

Comment: Yes, the folder is "res/values/dimens.xml" ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you should use `<dimen` instead of `<item`  and it should work

Answer (score 2):

You are declaring **item** elements here, not **dimen**.
For example this one works:

```
<resources>

    <dimen name="activity_horizontal_margin">16dp</dimen>
    <dimen name="activity_vertical_margin">16dp</dimen>

    <dimen name="reference">@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin</dimen>

</resources>
```