# Setting XML attribute with a variable

Tags: android

I'm trying to set an XML attribute with a variable in the resources in Android studio with no luck.

Something like this works:

```
<resources>
    <string name="Key">@string/Key</string>
</resources>
```

But something like this doesn't:

```
<resources>
    <string name="Key" custom-attribute="@string/Key"/>
</resources>
```

How do you use variables in XML attributes?

This is NOT the same question as [Android xml reference within xml doesn't work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30458841/android-xml-reference-within-xml-doesnt-work).

The first example works correctly, I am able to use variables setting a field value.  The second example does not work, I cannot set an attribute.

Comment: Can u please elaborate your question more ? What is the use case of this problem? where are you using this? There could be another method to solve your actual problem.

Comment: My use case is wanting different server urls in the Salesforce Mobile SDK.  Here is their documentation: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.mobile_sdk.meta/mobile_sdk/oauth_custom_login_host.htm

So I would like to have the server url change per environment.  I'm setting the server url as a variable in string.

Comment: Are you creating the server.xml file in the xml folder. You have to create a new directory with the name xml because by default it is not there.  In documentation you have to create <servers></servers> in the xml

Comment: Yes, I've gotten it working by hard coding the server url. I want to have the server url pull from a variable set at build time.  So I can have different build configurations that will auto set the server url.

Comment: I Guess you are using build.gradle for this if not you can also achieve this using build.gradle

Comment: How could you do it in build.gradle?

Comment: please check updated answer.

Comment: Your update sets a variable, it does not use that variable to set an attribute.  How would you then use that variable to set an attribute?

Answer (score 0):

Here we can define resources in res/ folder.
You can create your own file and use below examples.
The value thing won't work.

```
<resources>
<string name="button">Try Again</string>
<dimen name="margin">56dp</dimen>
<bool name="isCorrect">false</bool>
<color name="background">#fff</color>
<drawable name="icon">@drawable/ic_about_us</drawable>
<integer name="count">56</integer>
<string-array name="days">
        <item>Monday</item>
        <item>Sunday</item>
</string-array>
</resources>
```

And Use by `R.id.nameOfResource`
[Here](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/more-resources.html) is much more to explore about them.
Hope this helps.

Update: We can also define resources like this in build.gradle script.

```
    android {
    buildTypes.each {
        it.resValue 'string', 'serverLink', "https://mylink.com"
    }
}
```

Comment: Sorry, not seeing how this will enable me to set an XML attribute. For something like <string name="button" color="@string/buttonColor"></string>.  Wanting to have the color attribute pull from variables.

Comment: This is not valid I guess. As we cannot define a string or any type of resource like this. Even while defining our own style attributes we cannot give the string resource a type of colour and value of a string.

Comment: String and color are examples.  It could be <car name="ford" make="@string/carMake"></car>

Just looking for setting an attribute on an XML field to a defined variable.

Comment: please check the updated answer if this is helpful.

Comment: Thanks but I have that working already.  I have the variable, it's being defined per environment.  I need to now use that variable to set an XML attribute.

So in your example, you have a serverLink variable.  How would you use that to set <server url="???" />

Comment: Again it's hard coded in build.gradle just like above and we can't modify it but can be defined as per flavours and can be accessed via BuildConfig.VARIABLE_NAME

Comment: Not asking about setting a variable.  Asking about using that variable in an XML attribute.

Answer (score 0):

```
<resources>
    <string name="Key">Some Value</string>
</resources>
```

Should give you same result as:

```
<resources>
    <string name="Key" value="Some Value"/>
</resources>
```

Because of that I would recommend using the first example as that works properly.

Comment: Using Key and Value was probably a mistake as an example.  If you want to set a custom attribute is what I'm looking for.  Instead of Value could be anything, like Custom-Attr.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<string name="Key1">Some Text</string>
<string name="Key2">@string/Key1</string>
```

**update:**

```
<string name="Key1">Some Text</string>
<string name="Key2">
    <some-attribute>@string/Key1</some-attribute>
</string>
```

Comment: This works for XML value but not for setting an attributel

Comment: @DanCorey updated.

Comment: Thanks but fields and attributes are not the same thing.  Check out https://www.w3schools.com/xml/xml_dtd_el_vs_attr.asp